# Как наиболее правильно передать пост запрос?

Tags: php

Требуется передать пост запрос с русским названием.
Пока планирую так:

```
<input type="text" name="posts['Имя'] />
<input type="text" name="posts['Почта'] />
```

Правильно ли будет так передавать переменные? Или существуют другие способы?

Answer (score 1):

Может возникнуть проблема с кодировкой, к примеру при переносе на другой хостинг или если клиент пользуется старой версией браузера. 
И вообще, как мне кажется, это некрасиво и неправильно. Лучше так:

```
<input type="text" name="posts[name] />
<input type="text" name="posts[email] />
```

Или воспользоваться сURL.